# Kotlin form of Scala multiple _ [underscore] magic

Tags: scala, kotlin, lambda

In [Scala _ [underscore] magic](https://ananthakumaran.in/2010/03/29/scala-underscore-magic.html) Anantha Kumaran uses `_+_` as a shorten version of `(a,b)=>a+b`.

[image]

In [Kotlin Koans -- SAM conversions](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Introduction/SAM%20conversions/Task.kt) there is a similar bit of code `x, y -> y - x`. Is there a short version of this for Kotlin?

[image]

Comment: To begin with, it's not similar: it's `y - x`, not `x - y`. For `x - y` the closest approach would be `Int::minus`.

Comment: y - x ... -x + y

Answer (score 1):

No, Kotlin only has shorthand like that for single-argument lambdas (using name `it` rather than `_` and allowing to use it more than once).

Given how often I've seen people on Stack Overflow surprised by Scala `_` behavior and limitations, I think this is the right choice. (On the other hand, it Kotlin it would be limited because lambdas are always delimited by `{ }`, and surprises in Scala tend to come when they aren't.)

Comment: So Scala has a special case for a lambda with any number of parameters, each used exactly once, in order; Kotlin has a special case for a lambda with exactly one parameter, used any number of times.  In my experience, the latter happens much more often; the `_ + _` case is cute but not representative.  So I prefer Kotlin's choice.  I also think `it` reads better!  And when using multiple params, naming them becomes important to keep things clear.

Comment: @gidds Scala is even more special-cased than that: they also can't be inside parentheses except as a method parameter, e.g. `_ * (_ + _)` isn't `{ (x, y, z) => x * (y + z) }`, it's `{ x => x * { (y, z) => y + z } }`.